# Missing operator in date time selection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

```
 Dim rmfrom As Date
        rmfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(hapfromrm.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy", Nothing)
        Dim rmto As Date
        rmto = DateTime.ParseExact(hapfromrm.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy", Nothing)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM writes WHERE date_written BETWEEN " & rmfrom & " AND " & rmto & "", con)
```

It gives me the following error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'date_written
>   BETWEEN 1/2/2015 12:11:00 AM AND 1/2/2015 12:11:00 AM'.

What's the workaround?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The dates should be in quotes, i.e. '1/2/2015 12:11:00 AM' AND '1/2/2015 12:11:00 AM'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need properly formatted string expressions for the dates:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM writes WHERE date_written BETWEEN #" & rmfrom.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# AND #" & rmto.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#", con)
```